# Match one group of characters or another group of characters

Tags: java, regex

Some time ago I wrote a regular expressions that captures 1. name and 2. last name of person. I'm interested in only most simple names and surnames. Let's take the following string for example.

`John Smith`

My regular expression captures in its first group `John` and in its second `Smith`. Later on, I supplemented this regular expression by taking into account first name initial (one letter only followed by a dot). Let's have a look at example:

`John R. Smith`

My regex captures `John R.` as first capture group and `Smith` and the second.

Now I'd like to go one step further and capture in the first group two initials and have the rest of the regular expressions as is. Let's have a look at example:

`J. R. Smith`

I'd like to capture `J. R.` as first capture group and `Smith` as the second.
This is the part I need help with. Here's my regex:
[^(?\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+(?: \p{Lu}.)?) (?\p{L}\p{Ll}+(\p{Pd}\p{Lu})?\p{Ll}+)$](https://regex101.com/r/wm0qhR/1)

Comment: What you trying to do ? It;s common knowledge that given a list of names (only) there is no regex likely to be able to parse Names/Surnames accurately. I mean just look at some of the variations. Double (barrelled?) /triple or more surname ex: Sacha Baron Cohen https://regex101.com/r/f7sSJP/1 or your selected answer https://regex101.com/r/d6dSsX/1. I've been on the Regex tag 9 years, seen this question asked several times. What I'm telling you is the _Answer_. That someone attempted to answer is perplexing.

Comment: Did you read my question? I said I was interested in only very simple cases and even provided examples of them. Yet you claim you know the ANSWER. If you read my question carefully, you would have known that I don't deal with two first names, as you claim pointing out to the poor example of yours.

Comment: Are you only interested in `java` solution? Or possibly other regex dialects as well? Thx.

Comment: @jubilatious1 I'm happy with the answer I was given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is to update the current regex with an additional requirement, I'd suggest:

```
^(?<firstName>\p{Lu}(?:\.|\p{Ll}+)(?: \p{Lu}\.)?) (?<lastName>\p{L}\p{Ll}+(?:\p{Pd}\p{Lu})?\p{Ll}+)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/O6ATOp/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?<firstName>\p{Lu}(?:\.|\p{Ll}+)(?: \p{Lu}\.)?)` - Group "firstName":

  - `\p{Lu}` - an uppercase letter
  - `(?:\.|\p{Ll}+)` - a dot or one or more lowercase letters
  - `(?: \p{Lu}\.)?` - an optional sequence of a space, an uppercase letter and a `.`
- - space
- `(?<lastName>\p{L}\p{Ll}+(?:\p{Pd}\p{Lu})?\p{Ll}+)` - Group "lastName":

  - `\p{L}` - a letter, then
  - `\p{Ll}+` - one or more lowercase letters, then
  - `(?:\p{Pd}\p{Lu})?` - an optional sequence of a hyphen and then an uppercase letter and then
  - `\p{Ll}+` - one or more lowercase letters
- `$` - end of string.